# How do i run my python file from any directory on my computer [Arch]

Tags: python, pip

I am currently trying to run [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) on the `gmon.out` created by using the `-pg` option while compiling.

Now I have already done `pip install gprof2dot`. How am I supposed to run this on the `gmon.out` file that was created? Using the instructions given on the Github page(`gprof main | gprof2dot.py | dot -Tpng -o output.png`), I get the error:

> bash: gprof2dot.py: command not found

**Note**: My executable is called `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install gprof2dot` installs the script as `gprof2dot`, not `gprof2dot.py`.

Just remove the `.py` in your command and you should be good to go.

---

For future reference: You can enter a part of an unknown command at your shell prompt and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to try and auto-complete it (which I did in this case).

For packages installed via `pip`, you can also list the files they contain:

```
$ pip show -f gprof2dot
---
Name: gprof2dot
Version: 2015.12.01
Location: /tmp/tenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  ../gprof2dot.py
  ../gprof2dot.pyc
  ./
  SOURCES.txt
  dependency_links.txt
  top_level.txt
  PKG-INFO
  entry_points.txt
  ../../../../bin/gprof2dot
```

Anything that's executable should be in a `bin` directory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I performed pip install gprof2dot and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it wasn't working. I'm placing this here for posterity since it's the first link I found when trying to search for my solution. While the above statement by n.st is absolutely correct.

I tried searching the bin folder and gprof2dot was not found still.

I discovered I had to perform a sudo pip install gprof2dot (so I had to uninstall my original installation using pip uninstall gprof2dot, then re-install using sudo pip install gprof2dot).

Once I did the above I was able to use the gprof2dot that n.st was recommending.